# Compile Delphi component package (bpl) for different Delphi versions

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010, vcl

The situation is the following. Typically I use RAD Studio 2010 for Delphi development. I have some components I would like to redistribute in binary form (*.bpl without source). But I would like people to be able to use them despite of their Delphi version. But, for example, dcu files can be used only by compiler version, which generated them. Almost the same situation is with bpl files as I know. Every bpl file will require corresponding VCLXX.bpl library depending on Delphi version. How do I make my bpls, compiled in 2010 to be able to be used in Delphi7, 2007 etc?

Is the only solution to have ALL Delphi versions installed and compile bpl files separately in each?

Comment: potential 'bonus' question: are 'full' Delphi versions (no upgrades) required to build these BPL files? For example, after upgrading from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010, does the license allow to distribute BPLs created with the original Delphi 7 version *and* files created with the Delphi 2010 upgrade?

Comment: Yes, @mjustin, that's allowed. People do it all the time. My impression is that's what all component vendors do.

Comment: Most Delphi developers refuse to use components distributed without sources - exactly because you can't use a newer version of Delphi until updated packages are available, and if those packages becomes unmantained you have a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's the only solution.  Each compiler produces DCUs and BPLs specific to it's own version.  The only exception I'm aware of is that Delphi 2006 and 2007 share the same format.

Comment: To elaborate on this - component vendors that ship only binaries tend to package them into an installer that contains ALL of the supported binaries and then installs the ones that the user selects.

Answer (score 4):

To distribute compiled code that can be used by multiple compiler versions, distribute an ordinary DLL, not a BPL. Packages and units are version-specific.

Create standalone functions that you export in the C style, or create COM objects that get registered with the OS.

It doesn't have to change your entire development strategy, though; it could be a DLL that *uses* the BPL, so you can keep all the work you've already put into the package.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will require an application of my user to include my dll libraries. I don't think regular user will be glad to redistribute them.

Comment: That's what they'd have to do if your original plan — a BPL — were viable. There's no difference in that regard. (Although I hear there are ways to bundle a DLL within an EXE, for those people who really care how many files they distribute.)

Comment: Delphi can take code from BPL and integrate it into target EXE. There is no need to redistribute BPL separately.

Comment: No, Delphi can't do that. Perhaps you're thinking of the DCP file, which, as I understand it, is essentially a collection of all the DCU files that went into a package. But that file is only used when packages are being used, so you'd still need the BPL file.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an obj file in c++ builder and link that in Delphi, distribute a small pas file (header). The c++ builder obj format hasn'tchanged from delphi 7 to 2009 (I can confirm 2010 but I think it will be the same as well).

You would need to test though if this would be possible for visual/designtime components.

Answer (score 0):

I can create an installer that get the the installed Delphi versions on machine.
Choose for witch Delphi you want to create de bpl and call the correspondent Dcc by command line to generate the correspondents bpl and install in Delphi.
You can look in JVCL installer to get as example.

Att.

Comment: @SaCi, JVCL is redistributes in source form and is compiled to binary on target developer PC. So, this is not my case.